# Validate minimum word length in CKEditor

Tags: validation, ckeditor, min

Is there any client side javascript code which can validate the minimum word length in CKEditor.

For e.g. setting that a minimum of 500 words are required before the form can be submitted.

I tried a few JS validation scripts but they do not work specifically for CKEditor field.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Anyone there who can help with this?

Comment: What did you try, can you show the code you have? Also what code submits the actual form data? This should not be that difficult actually.

Comment: I believe I was able to fix it out but can't recall it now as its almost a year old :)

Comment: Oh I see. This was still unanswered so it's hard to know that :) Perhaps you could add the solution as an answer? I'm sure others are  looking for functionality like this too! (Also it clears the "unanswered list which is great)

Comment: I understand but its long time and I too lost track of this. Anyway, I will see if I can find the solution stored somewhere in the archives.

Comment: I have posted the solution for your reference please.

Answer (score 1):

I recall I was trying to accomplish this using Simfatic Forms JS form fields validation code.

I further believe the code was working but I couldn't figure it out because it offered two options for displaying validation message:

1. CSS method i.e. displaying validation messages next to the form fields.
2. JS Alert method i.e. displaying validation messages in a dialog box.

I was trying the 1st method which was actually interfering with CK Editor. I then switched over to the 2nd method and it worked.